# Facebook graph api - getting page public content access while in development mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wrote a short script for personal use only which is designed to get easier access to public content on facebook pages. The script is supposed to export the contents of public posts on a given page to an excel file.
I understand that for an app in live mode, I need to submit a request for page public content access in order to get information from pages that I don't manage. However, this script is not intended to go into live mode at all (for example, it doesn't have a user interface) as it is for my own use.
How can I get page public content access without turning the script into an app in live mode?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if you go live or not, if you want to access Pages you do not manage, you have to apply for Page Public Content Access. Else it would be easy to just keep in unpublished and redirect user calls to your code as a proxy to the Graph API. Facebook needs to know how you want to use the content.